# How to cretae a bitmap image from a byte arrayin androidwith java?

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I have a c# tcp server and i send a image byte array to my android client. But i have no success to convert array to bitmap.

```
This is my c# code:






    new Thread(() =>{
                        //İmage converter    
                        ImageConverter imConv = new ImageConverter();
//memory streaö                        
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
//bitmap               
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb555);
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bitmap.Size);
                        Cursors.Default.Draw(g, new Rectangle(new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y), new Size(Cursors.Default.Size.Width, Cursors.Default.Size.Height)));
                        bitmap.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                        Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
                        byte[] imgArry = (byte[])imConv.ConvertTo(img,typeof(byte[]));
                        tcpManager.SendTo(socket,imgArry);
                        bitmap.Dispose();
                        ms.Close();
                        ms.Dispose();
                        Thread.Sleep(41);

                                }).Start();
```

And this is my android client code, i get successfully the byte array but the function returns me a null bitmap

```
@Override
 public void OnReceived(byte[] byteData) {
 try{
      final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
      runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                                    screenView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                               }
                           });

                       }catch (Exception ex){
                       }
                   }
```

Comment: what are first lets say 8 bytes of `byteData`? comeare them to those [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures)

Comment: it say -119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10 and so go on ..... What/Where is my wrong?.

Comment: How can i solve my problem. My c# server have a problem i think. Are you have a solution for me?

Comment: png starts with 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A - your data is 77, 50, 4E, 47, 0D, 0A, 1A, 0A

Comment: Without ImageConverter how can i convert my image to png byte array in c#?

Comment: you have to check why your first byte is 0x77 - it should be 0x89 to be PNG, because you are sending png file arent you?

Comment: Yes i am trying to send PNG file, i dont know i am saving my image in memory stream maybe this will be my wrong

Comment: so just for testing, set the first byte of `byteData` to `0x89` and try again

Comment: No success, when i send text with same method i am getting success, i dont know where is my wrong :(

Comment: so compare byte-by-byte sent `imgArry` and received `byteData` - where do they differ?

Comment: `public void OnReceived(byte[] byteData)` What kind of client delivers you such a byte array?

Comment: is a C# Socket   i have a server in c#

Comment: With several debugging i find an error. My c# socket sent 189555 bytes but android client get 189554 bytes. Missing one byte